# Entries in a category not looping

Tags: channel-entries, categories

This is my code:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="products_insurance" style="linear"}
                <li data-submenu-id="submenu-{category_name}">
                    <a href="{path='borrow/#filter={category_url_title}'}">{category_name}</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            {exp:channel:entries category="{category_id}"}
                            <li><a href="{url}">{title}</a></li>
                            {/exp:channel:entries}

                         </ul>
                 </li>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

this part though:

```
{exp:channel:entries category="{category_id}"}
<li><a href="{url}">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

is not looping, it's only showing the entries for the first category.

This is for a custom dropdown menu I'm working on.

Any ideas why it's not looping? From what I can tell it should be.

Comment: Ok, What happens when you drop just the {category_id} in the outer loop? Do you get a full list of category_id's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JChrono asks, please verify the outer categories loop is putting all relivent ID's out.

Further still, to avoid any unwanted URL interference add the `dynamic` tag to your channel entries loop, also try forcing the parse order with `parse="inward"` on the categories loop, like so :

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="products_insurance" style="linear" parse="inward"}
  <li data-submenu-id="submenu-{category_name}">
    <a href="{path='borrow/#filter={category_url_title}'}">{category_name}</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        {exp:channel:entries category="{category_id}" dynamic="no"}
                        <li><a href="{url}">{title}</a></li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
      </ul>
   </li>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Just a couple of simple things to try first, let us know if we need to get more in depth on this.

Comment: yup. turning dynamic off in the entries loop did it, as well as the parse="inward". Simple answer as usual. I'm still gettting used to EE Tags.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :) `dynamic` simply tells the ee tags not to look to the URL for things like categories and titles (used for easy permalinking ect), however the `parse` parameter is somewhat of a secret squirrle! It's not properly documented.